# Gson doesn't properly convert a LinkedHashMap to JSON

Tags: java, json, gson, linkedhashmap

When I convert a LinkedHashMap directly to Json with GSON, it converts properly, but when I convert it as a class field, it doesn't convert properly. In another case I was working on, only the last element of the LinkedHashMap showed up in the final Json.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        System.out.println("GSON HashMap!");
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(hashMe()));
        System.out.println("GSON Zone!");

        //This doesn't give me the full LinkedHashMap
        System.out.print(gson.toJson(zoneMe()));
    }
    
    public ZoneChild zoneMe() {
        RateChild rate = new RateChild(hashMe());
        ZoneChild zone = new ZoneChild();
        zone.setName("Example");
        zone.setRate(rate);
        return zone;
    }
    
    public LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> hashMe() {
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> rates = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        rates.put(60, "data1");
        rates.put(25, "data2");
        rates.put(15, "data3");
        
        return rates;
    }
    
    public class Zone {
        RateChild rate;
        
        public Zone() {
        }
        
        public void setRate(RateChild rate) {
            this.rate = rate;
        }
    }
    
    public class ZoneChild extends Zone {
        private int level;
        private String name;
        
        public ZoneChild() {    
        }
        
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        
        public void setLevel(int level) {
            this.level = level;
        }
    }
    
    public class Rate {
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> rate = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        
        public Rate(LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> rate) {
            this.rate = rate;
        }
    }

    //I need this class for specialization
    public class RateChild extends Rate {
        
        public RateChild(LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> rate) {
            super(rate);
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
GSON HashMap!
{
  "60": "data1",
  "25": "data2",
  "15": "data3"
}
GSON Zone!
{
  "level": 0,
  "name": "Example",
  "rate": {
    "rate": {}
  }
}
```

I've noticed it doesn't fail when the LinkedHashMap field is directly in the Json converted class (ZoneChild).

Comment: isnt it just because you do nothing with the LinkedHashMap you pass to Rate? GSON only sees that `LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> rate = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();` is unchanged and thus returns empty rate

Comment: i.e., if you change the constructor of `Rate` to `this.rate = rate` or `this.rate.putAll(rate)` then your code should work as expected.

Comment: @Slaw Sorry, I forgot about that. No, that wasn't the problem. Just a typo.

Comment: Then it might be due to the visibility of Rate. Zone specifies Rate as default visibility, but it needs to be protected or public in order for it to be visible to ZoneChild

Comment: Question has too much code. 
Optimize it: add only that part of code that does not work correctly - debug your code see whats being happened in certain time of code interpretation. If it doen't help, take a screenshot with open debugger and ask you question with some more valuable information. Just putting your all code here will not help the community to answer correctly and many people even don't look such complex code base in less complex problem. Hope it will help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this with the code you provided; for me `$rate.rate` contains the expected output in the JSON data. Please make sure your example code really matches what you are actually using. For example the code you provided has compilation errors because `zoneMe`, `hashMe` and the nested classes all need to be `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce. Using Java 21.0.1 and Gson 2.10.1, the following code works as expected:

```java
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        data.put(60, "data1");
        data.put(25, "data2");
        data.put(15, "data3");

        Zone zone = new ZoneChild(new RateChild(data), "Example", 0);
        System.out.printf("##########  Original   ##########%n%n%s%n%n", zone);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        String jsonStr = gson.toJson(zone);
        System.out.printf("########## JSON String ##########%n%n%s%n%n", jsonStr);

        Zone decoded = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, ZoneChild.class);
        System.out.printf("##########   Decoded   ##########%n%n%s%n", decoded);
    }

    public static class Zone {

        RateChild rate;

        public Zone() {}

        public Zone(RateChild rate) {
            this.rate = rate;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Zone[rate=%s]", rate);
        }
    }

    public static class ZoneChild extends Zone {

        String name;
        int level;

        public ZoneChild() {}

        public ZoneChild(RateChild rate, String name, int level) {
            super(rate);
            this.name = name;
            this.level = level;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("ZoneChild[rate=%s, name=%s, level=%d]", rate, name, level);
        }
    }

    public static class Rate {

        LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> data;

        public Rate() {}

        public Rate(LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Rate[data=%s]", data);
        }
    }

    public static class RateChild extends Rate {

        public RateChild() {}

        public RateChild(LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> data) {
            super(data);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("RateChild[data=%s]", data);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
##########  Original   ##########

ZoneChild[rate=RateChild[data={60=data1, 25=data2, 15=data3}], name=Example, level=0]

########## JSON String ##########

{
  "name": "Example",
  "level": 0,
  "rate": {
    "data": {
      "60": "data1",
      "25": "data2",
      "15": "data3"
    }
  }
}

##########   Decoded   ##########

ZoneChild[rate=RateChild[data={60=data1, 25=data2, 15=data3}], name=Example, level=0]
```